# Twig: how to set object variable?

Tags: twig

I try to create new variable from exists object variable in Twig template (*filter* is object):

```
{% for filter in filters %}
    {% if filter.type != 'selectImage' %}
        {{ filter.render()|raw }}
    {% elseif filter.type == 'selectImage'%}
        {% set selectFilter = filter %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but i get error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Filters\Filter could not be converted to string in vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php(403) : eval()'d code on line 40
```

on

```
{% set selectFilter = filter %}
```

How i can set object to new vairable?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [official TWIG documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/filter.html), `filter` is the name of a tag in TWIG language.

You should rename your variable in your code to avoid problems in the generated PHP code:

```
{% set selectFilter = myFilter %}
```

Comment: Hm.. I updated the above example. The 'filter' variable using in _for_ cycle  and wok whitout problems.

Comment: The PHP error in your question is clear: you can't use the name "filter" for your TWIG variable. Rename the `filter` variable everywhere in your TWIG code to fix the error.